# GLIB: configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables in windows

Tags: gcc, cygwin, mingw, glib, msys

Configure Command is

Go to Glib Directory -> run this command

`./configure --prefix="Installation directory"`

While configure the Glib package in windows, It shows the following results.

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking for the BeOS... no
checking for Win32... yes
checking for Mac OS X Carbon support... checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/e/Projects/AVG/Tasks/SVGTask/RSVG/src/glib':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I am using minGW to compile the configure file from GLib package.I am using `mSys version 1.0 and Gcc 4.6.1 version`.

Both Cygwin and msys are installed in my system.

Even I tried with `cygwin` but the results are same.

**EDIT**

Log Details:

Provided the Error details contains in the log

```
  gcc version 4.6.1 (GCC) 
  configure:3363: $? = 0
  configure:3370: gcc -V >&5
  gcc.exe: error: unrecognized option '-V'
  gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
  compilation terminated.
  configure:3374: $? = 1
  configure:3397: checking for C compiler default output file name
  configure:3419: gcc  E:\Projects\AVG\Tasks\SVGTask\RSVG\include        E:\Projects\AVG\Tasks\SVGTask\RSVG\lib conftest.c  >&5
  d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find  E:\Projects\AVG\Tasks\SVGTask\RSVG\include: Permission denied
  d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find E:\Projects\AVG\Tasks\SVGTask\RSVG\lib: Permission denied
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  configure:3423: $? = 1
  configure:3461: result: 
  configure: failed program was:
  /* confdefs.h.  */
  #define PACKAGE_NAME "glib"
  #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glib"
  #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.20.5"
  #define PACKAGE_STRING "glib 2.20.5"
  #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=glib"
  #define GLIB_MAJOR_VERSION 2
  #define GLIB_MINOR_VERSION 20
  #define GLIB_MICRO_VERSION 5
  #define GLIB_INTERFACE_AGE 5
  #define GLIB_BINARY_AGE 2005
  /* end confdefs.h.  */

  int   main ()
  {

      ;
   return 0;
  }
  configure:3467: error: in `/e/Projects/AVG/Tasks/SVGTask/RSVG/src/glib':
  configure:3470: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried seeing `config.log` for those details yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Updated the config.log details.Please check log details.

Comment: I had the same error, the reason was the absence of '-' before 'O' in `CFLAGS=”O0...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you have the errors:

```
.../ld.exe: cannot find E:\Projects\AVG\Tasks\SVGTask\RSVG\include: Permission denied
.../ld.exe: cannot find E:\Projects\AVG\Tasks\SVGTask\RSVG\lib: Permission denied
```

Different users maybe...?

Comment: @ Ismael:how to solve this error? I am not having administrative privilage in my system.Please suggest how to overcome this.

Comment: You should ask someone with privileges to fix the permissions of those directories. Or alternatively, copy the files from somewhere else and use your copy instead.

Comment: @ Ismael: +1 for your solution.